# Sql server replace value of Update xml node value where node is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #HR_XML (ID INT IDENTITY, Salaries XML)
GO
INSERT #HR_XML VALUES(
'<Salaries>
  <Marketing>
    <Employee>
      <Salary>42000</Salary>
      <Incentive>12000</Incentive>
      <LeaveEncashment>12000</LeaveEncashment>
    </Employee>
  </Marketing>
</Salaries>
')

Select * from #HR_XML

Declare @Node Varchar(100) = ''
SET @Node = 'LeaveEncashment'

UPDATE #HR_XML
SET Salaries.modify('replace value of 
(/Salaries/Marketing/Employee/[@Node]/text())[1] with ("60000")')
GO

 Select * from #HR_XML

Drop Table #HR_XML
```

From the above sql queries, How to update/pass @node dynamically

Comment: If you are storing your XML in a variable (see comments in MikkaRin's answer), please don't supply your data as a table, this is misleading to those trying to answer your question. Please update your question to represent your actual data.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Dynamic sql](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

```
 CREATE TABLE #HR_XML (ID INT IDENTITY, Salaries XML)
    GO
    INSERT #HR_XML VALUES(
    '<Salaries>
      <Marketing>
        <Employee>
          <Salary>42000</Salary>
          <Incentive>12000</Incentive>
          <LeaveEncashment>12000</LeaveEncashment>
        </Employee>
      </Marketing>
    </Salaries>
    ')

Select * from #HR_XML


    Declare @Node Varchar(100) = ''
    SET @Node = 'LeaveEncashment'

declare @sql varchar(max)
Set @sql  = '    UPDATE #HR_XML
    SET Salaries.modify(''replace value of 
    (/Salaries/Marketing/Employee/'+@Node+'/text())[1] with ("60000")'')'

 exec (@sql)
    GO

   Select * from #HR_XML

   Drop Table #HR_XML
```

Comment: The problem with this method, is it's WIDE open to SQL injection. For example, If I were to instead pass `SET @Node = '/text())[1] with ("")''); DROP TABLE #HR_XML;--'`, that'll drop your table.

Comment: Above is not working in my scenario. Let's say if the XML is assigned to a variable then this dymanic query does not work.  Declare @variableName varchar(max) = '<Salaries>
      <Marketing>
        <Employee>
          <Salary>42000</Salary>
          <Incentive>12000</Incentive>
          <LeaveEncashment>12000</LeaveEncashment>
        </Employee>
      </Marketing>
    </Salaries>'
    '. Dymanic query will ask for variableName and say Must declare the scalar variable "VariableName"

Comment: @ArunKumar Variables and Tables are 2 completely different things. In your question  you provided a table, not a variable. What are we *really* working with here?